Using different data project and different billing project in Looker Studio BigQuery connection
Is there a workaround in Looker Studio, in which the BigQuery data source has a different projects for billing and for data?
The purpose whould be to have the queries run through the different project than the project where the data resides, so that the costs will be contained in one project, that is also using slot reservation API.
I created a service account in GCP, that has access to the project1 (data project) and project2 (billing project). I gave the SA, BigQuery Data Viewer and BigQuery User permissons on project1 and BigQuery Job User on project2.
Then i set up the BigQuery connection, using the SA credentials. When I want to use the data in the report, I see the error "No Data Set Access". Which is because the SA does not have a BigQuery Job User permission on project1.
Is there any other way about it?

It looks like when you use a Custom Query for the source of your data, you have the opportunity to specif a project that will be used for billing.  See the attached screen shot.

